# Kendo UI DropDownListFor selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I use Kendo UI for a dropdown list with HTML Helpers. When I want to set a default value for a View that is for editing the data .Value() doesn't work. Here's my code for the View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName)
         .Name("userName")
         .DataTextField("UserName")
         .DataValueField("UserId")
         .BindTo(Model.Mechanics)
         .Value(Model.UserName)
         )
```

And this is the code for the Action that gets the data:

```
public ActionResult EditServiceCart(int id)
        {
        var servCart = db.ServiceCarts.Where(x => x.CarId == id).SingleOrDefault();

        var mechanics = db.UserProfiles.Select(m => new MechanicsViewModel
        {

            UserId = m.UserId,
            UserName = m.UserName

        }).ToList();

        var model = new EditServiceCartViewModel
        {

            ServiceCartId = servCart.ServiceCartId,
            Mechanics = mechanics,
            UserName = servCart.UserName

        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

If I use a hardcoded binding (e.g .BindTo(new string[] {"Mechanic 1", "Mechanic 2", "Mechanic 3"})) .Value() works fine, but with my it's not. I saw that in the HTML the value that is displayed for the dropdown is in  and .Value method doesn't change it. It changed the value for the , which really is what I want but it's no matter because it's not displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName)
         .Name("userName")
         .DataTextField("UserName")
         .DataValueField("UserId")
         .BindTo(Model.Mechanics)
         .Value(Model.UserId) // Model.UserId(or something like that) NOT Model.UserName
         )
```

Because you told Kendo that : **"I'm going to use `UserId` as DropdownList Value"** .
When you pass **Model.UserName** to **.Value()** method, Kendo UI can't find that value